# angular dependency installation issue (npm install)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: cloud-share@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler-cli@15.2.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.2.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^16.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.1.3" from the root project

If i give npm install all necessary packages should install.

Comment: Which NodeJS version do you use? What does console print "node –version"?